# How to get the eigen decomposition of sparse matrices using armadillo or eigen libraries?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, eigenvector, armadillo

I have sparse square matrices of dimensions of the order of 10000 to 100000. I am using C++ programming language with armadillo and eigen as libraries for linear algebra which I know how to work with for dense matrices.

How can I get the eigen decomposition (eigenvalues and eigenvectors) of large sparse matrices using these libraries? Can we get the eigen decomposition from the Sparse Cholesky functions of Eigen?

Answer (score 3):

None of these libraries provide sparse eigenvalue decomposition. In Eigen unsupported/ you will find a wrapper to the ARPACK Fortran library. Please, note that computing all eigenvalues of a big large sparse matrix is prohibitively expensive. Usually, people compute only the largest ones that is what ARPACK can do.

Comment: Update: as of version 4.000, [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) supports [eigen decompositions](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_sym) of sparse matrices

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: No, knowing a Cholesky factorization (LL^T or LDL^T) is of no use for the eigenvalue problem.